# Parsing JSON to CSV using Python: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json, csv, nested

I have a nested JSON dataset containing multiple entries which look like this:

```
{
"coordinates": null,
"acoustic_features": {
    "instrumentalness": "0.00479",
    "liveness": "0.18",
    "speechiness": "0.0294",
    "danceability": "0.634",
    "valence": "0.342",
    "loudness": "-8.345",
    "tempo": "125.044",
    "acousticness": "0.00035",
    "energy": "0.697",
    "mode": "1",
    "key": "6"
},
"artist_id": "b2980c722a1ace7a30303718ce5491d8",
"place": null,
"geo": null,
"tweet_lang": "en",
"source": "Share.Radionomy.com",
"track_title": "8eeZ",
"track_id": "cd52b3e5b51da29e5893dba82a418a4b",
"artist_name": "Dominion",
"entities": {
    "hashtags": [{
        "text": "nowplaying",
        "indices": [0, 11]
    }, {
        "text": "goth",
        "indices": [51, 56]
    }, {
        "text": "deathrock",
        "indices": [57, 67]
    }, {
        "text": "postpunk",
        "indices": [68, 77]
    }],
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "urls": [{
        "indices": [28, 50],
        "expanded_url": "cathedral13.com/blog13",
        "display_url": "cathedral13.com/blog13",
        "url": "t.co/Tatf4hEVkv"
    }]
},
"created_at": "2014-01-01 05:54:21",
"text": "#nowplaying Dominion - 8eeZ Tatf4hEVkv #goth #deathrock #postpunk",
"user": {
    "location": "middle of nowhere",
    "lang": "en",
    "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
    "name": "Cathedral 13",
    "entities": null,
    "id": 81496937,
    "description": "I\u2019m a music junkie who is currently responsible for Cathedral 13 internet radio (goth, deathrock, post-punk)which has been online since 06/20/02."
},
"id": 418243774842929150
}
```

I want to convert it into a csv file in which there are multiple columns containing the respective entries for each JSON object. The following is the Python code I have written to do it:

```
import json
import csv
from pprint import pprint
data = []
with open('data_subset.json') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

# open a file for writing
data_csv = open('Data_csv.csv', 'w')
# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(data_csv)

for i in range(1,10):
    count = 0
    for dat in data[i]:
        if count == 0:
             header = dat.keys()
             csvwriter.writerow(header)
             count += 1
        csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
data_csv.close()
```

On running the above code,I get the error: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the JSON file all in once like:

```
with open('a.txt') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Now you have the JSON as the `data` dictionary.

Since you want specific entries from the JSON to csv (e.g. `entities` is not saved to csv) you can keep a custom column header and then loop over the data to write the particular keys to the csv:

```
# Example to save the artist_id and user id; can be extended for the actual data
header = ['artist_id', 'id']

# open a file for writing
data_csv = open('Data_csv.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(data_csv)

# write the csv header
csvwriter.writerow(header)

for entry in data:
    csvwriter.writerow([entry['artist_id'], entry['user']['id']])

data_csv.close()
```

Comment: The actual json file has 10000 entries in the format given above. So I think I will need to loop over the JSON objects and store them in an array. I want the csv file to have columns as the following:
{coordinates, instrumentalness, liveness, speechiness, danceability, valence, loudness, tempo, acousticness, energy, mode, key, artist_id, place, geo, tweet_lang, source, track_title, track_id, artist_name, created_at, text, location, lang, time_zone, name, entities, id, description}
Also, the entities which consist of the hashtags can have variable number of  text and indices fields.

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar, I have updated the answer based on your inputs. You can add other fields from the json to write them to csv.

Comment: What if I want to add hashtags columns to my csv file?

Comment: What if I want to add hashtags to my csv file?

Comment: What do you mean by hashtags? Can you show a sample row?

Comment: This is how the resultant file should look:  
user_id        hashtags   \n
81496937    nowplaying, goth, deathrock, postpunk  \n    
[user_id2]    [hashtag1, hashtag2]    \n
...                 ....

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar, I am not able to understand what exactly you want to do but I think this is something different from the original problem. I would suggest you to post a new question where you can probably add some snapshot of how you want the row to appear. That way the community would be able to help you faster and better.

Comment: Okay no problem.